# Delaying splash-screen on iOS in Phonegap build (editing existing deviceready-function)

Tags: ios, cordova, splash-screen

I want to delay the splash-screen in my Phonegap Build app for iOS (and avoid the white flicker). And have put this in my config.xml:

```
<gap:splash src="splash.png" width="640" height="960" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="1000" />
```

(The "SplashScreenDelay" has no effect). I know I also have to put something like this in my index.html:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    setTimeout(function () {navigator.splashscreen.hide()},4000);
        }
```

But I can't figure out how to combine this with my existing index.html which' body looks like this:

```
<body> 
    <div id="fb-root"></div>

    <canvas id="c2canvas" width="640" height="960">
        <h1>Your browser does not appear to support HTML5.  Try upgrading your browser to the latest version.  <a href="http://www.whatbrowser.org">What is a browser?</a>
        <br/><br/><a href="http://www.microsoft.com/windows/internet-explorer/default.aspx">Microsoft Internet Explorer</a><br/>
        <a href="http://www.mozilla.com/firefox/">Mozilla Firefox</a><br/>
        <a href="http://www.google.com/chrome/">Google Chrome</a><br/>
        <a href="http://www.apple.com/safari/download/">Apple Safari</a><br/>
        <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe">Google Chrome Frame for Internet Explorer</a><br/></h1>
    </canvas>

    <script src="jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>

    <script src="phonegap.js"></script>

    <script src="c2runtime.js"></script>

    <script>
        jQuery(window).resize(function() {
            cr_sizeCanvas(jQuery(window).width(), jQuery(window).height());
        });

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function ()
        {           
            // Create new runtime using the c2canvas
            cr_createRuntime("c2canvas");

            document.addEventListener("pause", function() {
                cr_setSuspended(true);
            }, false);

            document.addEventListener("resume", function() {
                cr_setSuspended(false);
            }, false);

        }, false);

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add:

```
setTimeout(function () {navigator.splashscreen.hide()},4000);
```

to the block you already have:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I'm not that much of a programmer, and my problem is that I don't know how EXACTLY to add that. Could you maybe show how to write the whole <script>-block?